# Sideloaded Chrome extension not showing for managed users

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-workspace

We're making a Chrome extension that will be built specifically for organizations. They will specify it as [a force-installed extension](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6306504?hl=en).

We've packed the extension with the latest crx3 format and verified that after packaging, we can install the extension in to Chrome by dragging it in to the extensions tab. It installs as expected and I've verified the extension ID is correct.

We have a test enterprise domain with a few chromebooks. We've gone through the process of specifying the custom app, but it's not showing up. I've verified the policy has updated both through the G Suite admin console and in chrome://policy on the users device. When looking at the policies, I see the extension we're force installed listed in the table on chrome://policy, but the extension itself isn't showing up in the extension list.

Is there a good way to debug why a managed extension isn't being installed from the enterprise policy?

Comment: Try https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: Good idea. It turns out there wasn't a bunch of extension-related stuff in there. But we did solve the problem due to issues with the update XML.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, we solved the problem due to a mixup of URLs in the update XML created for versioning.